# Compute properties of a transformed region?

Tags: bugs, regions

I want to find the centroid of a transformed region (which will be a symbolic expression):

```
p1 = Polygon[{{0.,0.}, {.3,0.}, {.3,1}, {0,1}, {0,0.9}, {.2,.9}, {0.2,0.1}, {0,0.1}}];
RegionCentroid @ p1
RegionCentroid @ TransformedRegion[p1, TranslationTransform[{0, x}]]
```

[image]

But this obviously doesn't work, I would expect an answer of `{0.207143, 0.5+x}, perhaps there is another way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I afraid you should give a report to W.R.And BTW,If you change the `x` into a number,the `RegionCentroid` will work.